# NVDA screen reader not working with mega menu keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

[On this page](https://www.vmdconseil.ca/en), the keyboard navigation works fine on my megamenu until I start NVDA screen reader: when I activate a menu item by hitting enter on my keyboard, instead of showing the menu panel, my browser opens the last anchor or button right before the menu in the markup. In this case it's the green login button on the upper right corner.

Has anyone seen this problem before?

Thank you

Comment: In what browser are you experiencing this?

Comment: I only tried with Chrome

Comment: NVDA users generally pair NVDA with Firefox, sometimes with IE.

Comment: I have the same problem with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not be in "browse mode."

Using NVDA (ideally with Firefox or even IE), press the `NVDA key` (probably `Caps-Lock` if you are on a laptop) and `Space`. Then navigate the page with the `Tab` key.

Once I switch modes, hitting the `Enter` key does what I think you want.

If you are unfamiliar with the different browse modes, take a look at [Understanding screen reader interaction modes](http://tink.uk/understanding-screen-reader-interaction-modes/). This passage may help:

> By creating a virtual copy of the document, screen readers make it
>   possible for blind people to interact with content in ways that would
>   otherwise be impossible on the Windows platform. This happens because
>   the screen reader intercepts most keypresses before they reach the
>   browser, triggering an interaction with the virtual document instead.

From a comment on that post:

> Actually some screen readers will fire the onClick event handler when
>   space or enter is pressed on an element while in virtual/browse mode.
>   This is one reason why an element can be activated via the keyboard
>   but not triggered from the keyboard when a screen reader is running.

[How Windows Screen Readers Work on the Web](http://www.ssbbartgroup.com/blog/how-windows-screen-readers-work-on-the-web/) is a similar resource that re-states much of the same.

Comment: While you are in there, I suggest a few tweaks to fix the `<label>` and field associations on that page and maybe making the "Log in" quasi-modal close when pressing the `Esc` key.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look!

The solution suggested is applicable only if the users switch modes. Do you think it's acceptable to assume they will?

Comment: I did, and I am not even a daily user. Alternatively, I am not a daily user.